# Onsen-UI Fixed Header on pages with Multiple Text Input Forms

Tags: ios, cordova, onsen-ui

I started a new Onsen-UI / Phonegap project for iOS 7+ and cant seem to make the HEADER BAR fixed when the keyboard comes up to interact with an input form. When the keyboard comes up it will push the fixed header bar out of the screen.

After i dismiss the keyboard it will then show the header again. But this makes it confusing for my users as the 'Submit' button is in the header bar. So unless the user closes keyboard they get 'lost/confused'.

Any suggestions?

-Dave

Comment: http://imgur.com/erWQiPy is a link to whats happening and what my desired result is.

Answer (score -1):

When keyboard comes up, the input form-element is focused and becomes centered.
Therefore if the input form-element is located at lower area in your layout, when the keyboard 
comes up, the form-element becomes centered and the header bar will move upwords and disappear.

I think your layout should be changed. The input form-element should be located at upper area.
Then the header bar does not disappear.

Another solution is dynamically layout changing. Before keyboard comes up, you can improve 
the layout dynamically by javascript and after keybaord dismissed you can restore the layout.

For example, the html is

```
<div class="upper_area">
...
</div>
<input type="text" class="input_name">.
```

An upper_area is something in your layout. 
This means the input form-element is located at lower area. 
The js is

```
$('#input_name').on('focusin' , function(e) {
  $('#upper_area').hide();
});

$('#input_name').on('focusout', function(e) {
  $('#upper_area').show();
});
```

This js changes the layout dynamically before the keyboard comes up.
The input form-element becomes at upper area before the keyboard comes up.
Therefore header bar does not disappear.

In the above code, I use the jQuery (version >= 2.0.0) for simplicity.